# How to execute PHP artisan on Docker PHP container

Tags: php, laravel, docker, docker-compose

I have set a Docker environment for a `Laravel` project with `Docker-compose` on a `Windows 10` machine:

```
version: '3'

networks:
  laravel:

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    container_name : nginx
    ports:
      - "8088:80"
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
      - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    depends_on:
      - php
      - mysql
    networks:
      - laravel

  mysql:
    image : mysql:5.7.22
    container_name: mysql
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "4306:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: laravel
      MYSQL_USER: admin
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
    networks:
      - laravel
  
  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: php
    volumes: 
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    networks:
      - laravel
```

I have also created a `DockerFile`:

```
FROM php:8.0-fpm-alpine
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql
```

Everything is working fine. However, I've having difficulties understanding how to run `artisan`. From what I have seen online, I should run `docker-compose exec php php /var/www/html/artisan ...`. But I'm getting this message from `Docker`:

```
`Could not open input file: C:/Users/lharr/AppData/Local/Programs/Git/var/www/html/artisan`
```

which makes sens since this path doesn't exist. But why is `Docker` going to this specific repository `C:/Users/lharr/AppData/Local/Programs/Git/` ? and isn't the volumes defined in `Docker-compose` supposed to create `/var/www/html/artisan` repository ? How can I find out where `PHP` is stored and how can I properly execute `artisan` command inside this container ?

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the command in `"` like `docker exec php "php /var/www/html/artisan ..."`

Comment: @Spirit Same result.

Comment: Another option is to connect to the container and execute the command within: `docker exec -it php sh`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the solution to this problem was quite simple : No need to specify the full path to `artisan` while executing the command. Meaning, instead of `docker-compose exec php php /var/www/html/artisan ...`, `docker-compose exec php php artisan` is enough.